# IntelliJ - Step Into

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I want to use the option of "step into" in the debugger. But, I want that the debugger enters only function that are implemented in specific files. For other functions, "step into" will behave like "Step Over".

Comment: Then don't use Step into. Put a breakpoint in your "specific files", and resume to the next breakpoint.

Comment: I want to be able to hit the same mapkey and move from line to line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the debuggers stepping configuration to define where you want the debugger to stop and where not.

[image]

Or you can put a breakpoint to a start point from where you want to examine the behavior of your code and then put breakpoints in your specific files/implementations.

Furthermore, it would be very helpful if you describe your problem in more detail.